# Creating a "Last Name, First Name" entry in the index for OPmac

Tags: plain-tex, opmac

I'm trying to create an index entry that looks like:

`Knuth, Donald E.  4`

Where `Donald` is the first name of a person and `Knuth` is his last and `E.` his middle initial. From what I can tell, the comma character is used as part of the syntax of index entries and thus is not directly available for the text of an index entry.

There is a special support macro, `\iis` whose intent is to assist in sorting when unusual characters are part of the text.  Using that macro I came up with the following:

`The computer scientist \iis DonEKnuth {Knuth, Donald E.} \ii DonEKnuth Donald E. Knuth is well known for ...`

That is an obviously cumbersome way to deal with the issue and I thought that perhaps there is a better way (within OPmac)?

p.s. `eplain` (which uses `makeindex`) has the macros `\sidxname{Donald E.}{Knuth}[subterm] and \idxname{Donald E.}{Knuth}[subterm]` for this purpose.  Although it isn't strictly required since one could simply use `\sidx{Knuth, Donald E.}`, etc.` directly.

Comment: I'd like to add that `\iis` can be used as a general solution to doing any special typesetting for an index entry.  For example from what I can tell, macros such as `\it` and `\em` can only be typeset by using `\iis`.  This can make for an unfortunately verbose index entry but, at least for me, isn't needed too often.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution I've discovered is to use `\iindex`:

`... \iindex{Knuth, Donald E}Donald E. Knuth is ...`

This does not seem to have problems handling the comma.

Comment: OK, but I recommend to remove the space: `\iindex{word}next text ...` This is important difference between usage of `\ii word<space>` and `\iindex`.

Comment: Yes, I had already discovered that but forgot to edit the anwer. Thanks.